# Where does Plesk pull its list of available shells under the domain setup page?

Tags: centos

Does anyone know where Plesk pulls its list of available shells under the domain setup page? I am on a box which is missing `/bin/bash` (chroot), though the majority of the system users on the machine have the shell:

```
/usr/local/psa/bin/chrootsh
```

On a redhat/centos machine, chrootsh is provided by the base psa package. I have also checked that chrootsh is specified in `/etc/shells`. I have poked around the psa database, but have not been able to ascertain where the drop down box is populated from.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that plesk does use /etc/shells. However, /bin/bash (chrooted) is a special case. If the /bin directory at /bin contains certain files that are not executable, /bin/bash (chrooted) will not be in the list.